# how to convert date in to hindi date for example 7 march 2011 to ७ मार्च २०११

Tags: c#, datetime, hindi

I am developing a Win Form application using C#. The application shows some information in English and Hindi.

How can I convert date in to Hindi?

For e.g. 7 march 2011 to  ७ मार्च २०११
so that it can be displayed on a label.

```
belateText = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Comment: you should use culture specific values. It is not more related to C#. It is culture specific question and use utf8 encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("hi"));
```

returns `30 नवम्बर 2013`

And if you want to see the digits in hindi, you would need to have the hindi language pack installed on the machine.